# Create single.php for specific tag by tag id or name

Tags: functions, tags

i have multiple tags and want to create multiple single.php for everyone tag.

**How create single.php for tags??**

> This code working well for category, how to edit it for tags??

```
 function my_category_templates($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ( in_category( 'raspee' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-raspee.php';
 }
  return $single_template;
 }
 add_filter( "single_template", "my_category_templates" );
```

Comment: has_tag('tag_name')

Comment: Thanx its working

Comment: Excellent I have posted an answer with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_tag()` is a function that will check if a `post` has a certain tag

You could integrate it into your code like so:

```
function my_category_templates($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ( in_category( 'raspee' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-raspee.php';
 }

 if ( has_tag( 'everyone' )) {
    $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-everyone.php';
 }

  return $single_template;
 }
 add_filter( "single_template", "my_category_templates" );
```

you can check out this function here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/